# Is using lambdas and overload resolution a recommended way to write a visitor for a variant?

Tags: c++, lambda, method-overloading, visitor-pattern, unions

If I have a discriminated union and want to write a function piecewise, the following code works just fine, but is taking advantage of some fairly tricky (at least to me) stuff involving overload groups:

```
struct A { };

struct B { };

typedef std::variant<A, B> C;

void f(const A & a) { std::cout << "a" << std::endl; }

void f(const B & b) { std::cout << "b" << std::endl; }

void f(const C & c) { std::visit([](const auto & x){ f(x); }, c); }
```

Is this a recommended way of doing things?  Once it's actually written it seems superior to, say, writing something using `holds_alternative`.

I have tried to look up what people suggest online, but most of the examples I've seen that make use of `std::visit` involve writing literal pages of incomprehensible boilerplate to create visitor classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a recommended way of doing things?

Yes, that's a fairly normal way of `visit`ing an overloaded function. The issue it solves is that `f` doesn't denote an object, but instead an *overload-set* of functions. Wrapping it in a lambda expression gives you an object.

The only *slightly* strange thing in that example is you include `void f(const C & c)` in the overload set. If you miss a case in the variant, you will end up with an infinite recursion if you try to visit that alternative.

> involve writing literal pages of incomprehensible boilerplate

I'm not sure what you have found, but the other normal way isn't [pages of boilerplate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit#Example), either a generic lambda or an "overload" functor from constituent lambdas.